# FMS 4 playing P2P stream with RTMFP

Tags: flash-media-server, netstream, rtmfp

**Proper disclosure:** I posted this question on the Adobe forums too. Since I didn't get any answer - I am posting it here. Sorry if it disturbs.

We are working with FMS 4 server for a while for a 2 directions video application, and it works great with RTMP.
We now want to use its rtmfp abilities after we used Cirrus for testing in the last few days and it also worked well.

Locally - everything is working fine, but when we try the application on a remote server - we have some problems.

Each side get the NetStatusEvent code "NetConnection.Connect.Success" and "NetStream.Publish.Start" when publish starts.

However, when we are trying to play the stream, nothing happens for a minute and than we get " NetStream.Connect.Closed" after about a minute.

(Locally, we are getting "NetStream.Play.Start" and "NetStream.Play.Reset").

I did open ports 1024-65535 UDP on the server and since we are able to connect Cirrus, I believe the clients are fine.

I also changed the Adaptor.xml HostPort element to
:19350-65535 where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the same public IP of our FMS Server as the one used by the client.

Again, it is working beautifully both locally and with Cirrus. RTMP also works well with the remote server.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I can't really help but tell you that I had a very similar problem but the other way around.
When I tried to connect two devices via Cirrus over our WLAN, I got the same error as you. When testing with one device in WLAN and the other in another Network it worked. Then I tested them both in the same WLAN (but in a WLAN other than ours) and it also worked. My collegue then updated some firmware (on the router? I'm not sure...) and deleted some VOIP data. Then it worked here, too.

I think maybe there is some problem at the remote server. UDP has to be allowed... but I'm sure you know that.
Sorry again for not really helping - but maybe this is at least a bit encouraging.

Do you know this sample: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/samples/ ?
I always tested with that so I knew it wasn't some problem with my code.